# How can I make data properties reactive in Vue?

Tags: vue.js, single-page-application

Hope evrything is fine.

I am trying to make data in vue instance reactive:

```
new Vue({// eslint-disable-line no-new
  el: '#app',
  data () {
    return {msg: 'not updated'}
  },
  router,
  components: { App },
  template: '<App/>',
  mounted () {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stores').then(response => (console.log(response.data.data)))
  }
})
```

Now When I try to use `{{msg}}`. But I get an **error** :

> property or method "msg" is not defined on the instance but referenced
>   during render

Any reason ?

Comment: Could you just share your markup as well?

Comment: Where did you try to use it?

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr in the app.vue <template>
  <div id="app">
    {{msg}}
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
  </div>
</template>

Comment: So  you should declare this variable at the app component or pass it in as a prop like this: <App :msg="msg" />

Comment: I am using it the app component

Comment: So pass is in the app  component  as parameter (look at my previous comment)

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr still not working

Comment: @KasabuckiAlexandr already answered your question, however to properly help you it would be pretty nice if you could provide a minimal working example of your code in a live example.

Answer (score 0):

For component 'App' set props :

```
new Vue({
    name: 'App',
    //set props msg for recieve from parent
    props: {
        msg: String
    },
    router,
    template: '<p>{msg}</p>'
  })
```

and pass msg from you component template:

```
<App :msg="msg" />
```

Comment: What I have in App.Vue <template>
  <div id="app">{{msg}}
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
  </div>
</template>

Answer (score 0):

It worked :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    {{msg = 'AA'}}
    <img src="./assets/logo.png">
  </div>
</template>

new Vue({// eslint-disable-line no-new
  el: '#app',
  props: {
    msg: String
  },
  router,
  components: {App},
  template: '<App />',
  mounted () {
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/stores').
    then(response =>(console.log(response.data.data)))
  }
})
```

Comment: My question If I have an array and I want to assign it how can I do that ?